# Pandas dataframe groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in Pandas so please bear with me. I know this is a very basic question/

I am working with pandas on the following dataframe :

```
x      y             w  

1      2             5                 
1      2             7         
3      4             3        
5      4             8    
3      4             5    
5      9             9
```

And I want the following output :

```
x   y   w   

1   2   5,7    
3   4   2,5    
5   4   8    
5   9   9
```

Can Anyone tell me how to do it using pandas groupby.

Comment: Is the `w` column of type string or is that an array in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) `join`:

```
#if type of column w is not string, convert it
print type(df.at[0,'w'])
<type 'numpy.int64'>

df['w'] = df['w'].astype(str)

print df.groupby(['x','y'])['w'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
   x  y    w
0  1  2  5,7
1  3  4  3,5
2  5  4    8
3  5  9    9
```

If you have duplicates, use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print df
   x  y  w
0  1  2  5
1  1  2  5
2  1  2  5
3  1  2  7
4  3  4  3
5  5  4  8
6  3  4  5
7  5  9  9

df['w'] = df['w'].astype(str)
print df.groupby(['x','y'])['w'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.drop_duplicates()))
        .reset_index()

   x  y    w
0  1  2  5,7
1  3  4  3,5
2  5  4    8
3  5  9    9
```

Or modified [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37049022/2901002) solution:

```
print df.groupby(['x','y'])['w'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str).drop_duplicates()))
        .reset_index()

   x  y    w
0  1  2  5,7
1  3  4  3,5
2  5  4    8
3  5  9    9
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But this repeats values. Like if I have the same values for w for the same (x,y), it repeats the value in the output. How can I handle that?

Comment: Glad can help you. Nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` on columns 'x' and 'y' and apply a lambda on the 'w' column, if required you need to cast the `dtype` using `astype`:

```
In [220]:
df.groupby(['x','y'])['w'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))

Out[220]:
x  y
1  2    5,7
3  4    3,5
5  4      8
   9      9
Name: w, dtype: object

In [221]:
df.groupby(['x','y'])['w'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()

Out[221]:
   x  y    w
0  1  2  5,7
1  3  4  3,5
2  5  4    8
3  5  9    9
```

**EDIT**

on your modified sample:

```
In [237]:
df.groupby(['x','y'])['w'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique().astype(str))).reset_index()

Out[237]:
   x  y    w
0  1  2  5,7
1  3  4  3,5
2  5  4    8
3  5  9    9
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But this repeats values. Like if I have the same values for w for the same (x,y), it repeats the value in the output. How can I handle that?

Comment: The normal etiquette here is to post sample data that is representative of your problem, iteratively incrementing or adding new information after people have answered is counter-productive and annoying